# How to animate width to auto using Animated in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I have a button that is 40x40, now this button has an active state where the container of the button extends and menu items come in. The active state has no specific width to it and should extend to accommodate for the content (something like `width: auto;` in CSS).

Is there a way how I could use animate this width change using `Animated`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out this https://hackernoon.com/playing-with-react-native-animations-d065e7e97391

Comment: is this is what you looking ? https://codesandbox.io/s/3vrly046k5